# change violinplot stick color in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Id like to be able to change the color of individual sticks in seaborn's violin plot to highlight a specific datapoint. Any seaborn pros have ideas how to do this?

[image]

Comment: You can get a list of the Line2D objects using `ax.lines`. Although with no [mcve] it's hard to tell how you are selecting which line should have a different colour?